# In description logics, how do you define a concept?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

In some texts I read I see a concept defined as a subset and in other texts I see it defined with equivalence.

Eg 1: Person is a subset of hasMother.Person and hasFather.Person

Eg 2: Mother is equivalent to Woman and hasChild.Person

When is it appropriate to use subset and when is it appropriate to use equivalence? I can't seem to find a distinction between the two.

Answer (score 1):

The second one is a defintion; so, it is appropriate to use equivalence.

The *concept* $\text {Mother}$ is defined as the [intersection of the two concepts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Description_logic#Concepts) : $\text {Woman}$ and $\text {hasChild.Person}$.

Reagrding the first one, we have that $\text{Person}$ is a concept, whose meaning is the class of all humans. Also $\text {hasMother.Person}$ is a concept and its meaning is again the class of all humans, because every human has a mother.

Thus the two concepts have the same meaning, and this implies that, given an interpretation $\mathfrak I$ with *domain* $\Delta$ containing all human beings :

> $(\text{Person})^{\mathfrak I} = (\text {hasMother.Person})^{\mathfrak I} \subseteq \Delta$.

In this sense, we have both :

> > $(\text{Person})^{\mathfrak I} \subseteq (\text {hasMother.Person})^{\mathfrak I} \text {  and  } (\text {hasMother.Person})^{\mathfrak I} \subseteq (\text{Person})^{\mathfrak I}$.

Comment: Thank you. I still seem to be missing something critical though. How would one know whether they ought to use equivalence or subset? What is the ultimate deciding factor? I am trying to formulate my own axioms for a project and I'm still stumped...

Comment: @Dee : $\subseteq$ is used with sets and sets are the *interpretation* of concepts. Concepts are rnelations are aprt of the language and we use definitions (which needs equivalence) to add new "names" to the language.